# How do I prevent C-j from exiting copy-mode in tmux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I like to use `C-j` to navigate down in `tmux` without a prefix, as I find it easier to navigate this way:

```
bind -n C-k selectp -U # switch to panel Up
bind -n C-j selectp -D # switch to panel Down
bind -n C-h selectp -L # switch to panel Left
bind -n C-l selectp -R # switch to panel Right
```

This works great in most circumstances, except when I am scrolling and want to move to a pane below without interrupting the "scroll mode" (I think it's called `copy-mode` in the documentation). If I hit `C-j` it just interrupts the scrolling, then hitting `C-j` again takes me to the bottom window. Using `prefix Down` works fine and has the intended behaviour of moving me to the bottom pane while not interrupting the scroll.

I tried adding `unbind C-j` to my `.tmux.conf` but this didn't seem to have any effect. Any ideas? Here is my `.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind C-j # doesn't do anything

bind -n C-k selectp -U # switch to panel Up
bind -n C-j selectp -D # switch to panel Down
bind -n C-h selectp -L # switch to panel Left
bind -n C-l selectp -R # switch to panel Right

unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix
```

Steps to reproduce:

I open a debian console in Windows, open `tmux` and use `prefix "` to open a horizontal split:

[image]

Then I enter `copy-mode` by pressing `prefix [`:

[image]

Now I press `C-j` I stay in the top window, but I've been kicked out of scroll mode:

[image]

Pressing `C-j` again moves me down to the bottom window:

[image]

The relevant output of `tmux list-keys`:

```
user@DESKTOP-R0IJO21:~$ tmux list-keys | grep C-j
bind-key    -T copy-mode-vi C-j               send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel
bind-key    -T root         C-j               select-pane -D
```

Comment: To wipe `bind -n C-j …` you need to `unbind -n C-j`, the flag matters. But if you `unbind` first and `bind` later then `bind` will win. Anyway, I'm not able to replicate the "interrupted scrolling mode" problem (in tmux 2.6); or I don't understand the problem. Unless I *also* `bind -T copy-mode C-j send-keys -X cancel`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried `unbind -n C-j` but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I added repro steps to my question if that helps. Maybe it's something to do with the fact that I'm on windows?

Comment: What is the output of `tmux list-keys | grep C-j`? In Ubuntu I have some default(?) binding for `copy-mode-vi` but I don't use this mode. Do you?

Comment: For future reference: the screenshots would be much more useful if they pictured a reasonably small window.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yeah that's fair I'll do that next time. I've included the output of `tmux list-keys`. It does have one entry that looks suspicious (`send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel`) but I'm not sure why this is there or how to remove it.

Comment: You remove it with `unbind -T copy-mode-vi C-j`. Again: do you use the vi mode? This would explain the behavior.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that fixed it, thanks. I'm not intentionally using vi mode, how can I check? It's not in my `.tmux.conf` file as far as I can tell...

Comment: http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#mode-keys